# Understanding flaky Django tests: Creation order affecting array order

Tags: python, django, testing

I have a test in Django that looks something like this:

```py
class WebhookClientSerializerTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_serializes_agent_from_client(self):
        agent1 = factories.AgentUserFactory(email='dave@agently.com')
        agent2 = factories.AgentUserFactory(email='jim@agently.com')
        client = factories.ClientFactory(agents=[agent1, agent2])
        schema = serializers.WebhookClientSerializer() # do some stuff
        data = schema.dump(client).data
        self.assertEqual(data['agents'][0]['email'], 'dave@agently.com')
        self.assertEqual(data['agents'][1]['email'], 'jim@agently.com')
```

We create a entity called an `Agent`, then another, and run through some custom serializer logic. The serializer returns an array of serialized agent data. There are other tests defined within the same class.

However, sometimes the agents come out in the wrong order. It fails with

```
AssertionError: u'jim@agently.com' != 'dave@agently.com'
```

I had assumed that when the entities were created, that it would be done sequentially. This test runs fine locally, but it fails in CI/CD sometimes, not always. We use the `--parallel` flag when running tests, but I don't see where or how the asynchronicity is messing with the order of the output array.

Why does the order change, and how could I write this test more robustly?

Comment: Just don't assume they're gonna come in a certain order if your serializer isn't ordering them in a certain way. You can just check that `len(data['agents']) == 2`, and that `dave@agently.com` and `jim@agently.com` are both in the list of agents.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using self.assertDictEqual(dict_a, dict_b)

It has nothing to do with parallel as the test case is not done by two processes.
You should always aim to use the most specific assertion it helps a lot to reduce occasionally failing tests.